# IIS re-write from http to https only for subdomains of one domain only

Tags: iis, web-server, iis-7, rewrite

I have an IIS7 web server with several sites running. Some of the sites are sub-domains of one domain and the others are totally separate domains. I want to use IIS re-write to redirect all the sub domain sites of one domain to https, but I want the other domains left as they are. For example I have the following sites on the same web server:

one.test.com,
two.test.com,
otherdomain.com

And I want to setup a global IIS rewrite to redirect http://one.test.com and http://two.test.com to https, but otherdomain.com should not be affected.

Here is what I have so far, and when I've  tested the regex it seems correct but it is not redirecting the subdomain sites:

```
<rewrite>
            <globalRules>
                <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)(\.test\.com)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{R1}{R2}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
            </globalRules>
        </rewrite>
```

Am I over complicating this or missing something obvious?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add *conditions* that match HTTP_HOST to your rule (the "url" variable in URL Rewrite doesn't include hostname).

```
<globalRules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.+)\.test\.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:0}/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</globalRules>
```

This rule should redirect all requests on *.test.com to HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this condition  `<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />` in the above solution. Otherwise it will ends in a loop. So the rule will be as follow,

```
<globalRules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.+)\.test\.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:0}/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</globalRules>
```